# Syntax Error: unexpected identifier - Binary algorithm code. Help me improve it

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm, binary

**What I would like to do:** 
some how create a variable that represents the binary system more accurately because I have only included the first 12 numbers, but what if I need many of the higher numbers! It needs to be more generic.

**What I have tried to do:** push the binary numbers that go into n to a new array called one, then return the length of the array as the answer.

```
var countBits = function(n) {
  Let binary = [1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64, 128, 256, 512, 1024, 2048];
  var one = [];
  for( let i = 0; i < binary.length; i++) {
  if( n = [i]) { one.push([i])},
  if( n > [i]) { one.push([i])},
  else { return "negative"};
  return one.length;

};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Syntactic problem

Following my comment, here is the correction:

- `let` instead of `Let`
- remove the `,` on both `if statements`
- a missing `}`

I would recommend you use some kind of editor to help tidy and validate your code.

It will save you a lot of time!

```js
var countBits = function(n) {
  let binary = [1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64, 128, 256, 512, 1024, 2048];
  var one = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < binary.length; i++) {
    if (n == [i]) {
      one.push([i])
    }
    if (n > [i]) {
      one.push([i])
    } else {
      return "negative"
    }
  }
  return one.length;
};
```

---

### Solving the actual *bit-counter* problem

Now onto the problem, you would like to:

> count the number of set bits on the binary representation of a given number

We will run our loop as long as `n` is not positive or equal to zero. On each loop, we will check if `n` is odd in which case we will add `1` to our counter. Then we will divide `n` by 2.

```js
const countBits = function(n) {
  let count = 0;
  while (n > 0) {
    count += (n % 2 != 0);   // add one to the counter if n is pair
    n = Math.floor(n/2);     // divide n by 2
  }
  return count;
}
```

---

You can do the exact same using binary operators: `&` (bitwise AND) and `>>` (right-shift). We will be working on `n` directly and counting down to determine the number of set bits.

Here are our two lines, now using `&` and `>>`:

1. On each loop, we will compare `n` with `1` *bit-wise*. Essentially `n & 1` will equal to `1` if `n` is dividable by `2`, else it will equal to `0`.
2. Then we will shift `n` by one, i.e. move all bits to the right. `n >>= 1` is the same as assigning the result of `n >> 1` to `n`: `n = n >> 1`.

```js
const countBits = function(n) {
  let count = 0;
  while (n > 0) {
    count += n & 1;
    n >>= 1;
  }
  return count;
}
```

More on [*bitwise operators*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators).

---

### One-liner

If you want to test your code out, here's a cheated version to compare your results to:

```js
const countBits = function(dec) {
  return (dec >>> 0).toString(2).split('').filter(Number).length;
}
```

It first converts the number to a string of its binary representation, then converts it to an array of `0`s and `1`s, remove the zeros with a [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter), then counts the number of remaining elements.